# Unity Android created CSV file visible on device, not on PC via USB

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, usb

I have a unity application that does a simple file creation and save on a CSV file.

```
    public void WriteDataToCsv() {
    StreamWriter outStream = File.CreateText (Application.persistentDataPath  + "/" + path);
//      GameObject.Find ("DebugText").GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Saved file to: " + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + path;
    outStream.WriteLine (sb);
    outStream.Close ();

}
```

Using any file explorer app off the Play store (both File Manager and X-Plore) I am able to see the file, and even edit it if i want. Its listed under Internal Storage\Android\data\com.test.app\files\data.csv

On the PC side, i can mount my Google Pixel, navigate to the same location (Internal Storage\Android\data\com.test.app\files) but the folder is empty.

I've tried plugging and unplugging in the phone, changing the USB file transfer mode on the phone, etc...

Anyone have any ideas?
Windows 10, and the phone is a Google Pixel 128gb.
Again, i can find the file and see the data there on the phone, but not on the PC. Are there permissions i need to be setting?!

Comment: `Internal Storage\Android\data\com.test.app\files\data.csv`. That is not a valid Android path to begin with. Take a decent app like ES File Explorer which will tell you the real path.

Comment: The MTP protocol between phone and pc uses the MediaStore. It looks as if you did not inform the MediaStore about your new file. Switch your device off/on will do that too.

Comment: You seem to be correct - after restarting the device, I am now able to see the data on my PC.
So how do I then update the mediastore from Unity? I don't want to have to restart the phone every time i need to get data off it..

Comment: I do not know Unity. But if you google for the normal java code to update the mediastore for a newly created  file (only a few lines) you probably will get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like that and I've been able to see the file changing right away. After restarting your phone, the folder turns available. So if you change something in the file when you plug your phone, the file should be updated.