# Is it possible to download or print the notification history in Android app?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to keep a log of notifications arriving in my app and to print or to download those notifications as a pdf format file to print it down?

I am developing an Android App for maintenance, so I want to keep those notifications as a log and print it down at last.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

um. yeah. click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674819/writing-txt-file-in-android/52674905#52674905)

this is a question about how to have a txt file to the native android path, so basically you will use this method to "Append" to, meaning you will open the file, write your new notification data, and add it to the end of the file.

the easiest way to do this is to store it in a string and then add that string to the end of your file if it exists. if it dosnt exists you create it.